# how to declare global function or method using c#?

Tags: c#

Can anyone tell me how to declare a global function in c#, similar to what a `Module` does in VB.net?
I need to call a function that can be called in my form1, form2, and form3.

---

i have this code :

```
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace XYZ
{
    public static class Module
    {
        public static void dbConnection()
        {
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "provider= microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=..\\dbCooperative.mdb";
            con.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

and form1:

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
using XYZ;

namespace XYZ
{
    public partial class frmReports : Form
    {
        public frm1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Module.dbConnection();
            OleDbCommand cm = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM table", con);
        }
    }
}
```

but i has an error: "The name 'con' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: There are NO global functions in C#, but you can make methods globally accessible in your application.

Comment: Although they are supported by the CLR, C# itself does not support "Global Functions". As far as I know, if you want to call them, you'd have to either write that logic in VB (or another language that does support them), or modify the compiled IL yourself. In your case, the suggestions for using a static class should suffice.

Answer (score 30):

If you're using C# 6.0 or later, you could use [`using static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static).

For example,

```
using static ConsoleApplication.Developer;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Global static function, static shorthand really 
            DeveloperIsBorn(firstName: "Foo", lastname: "Bar")
                .MakesAwesomeApp()
                .Retires();
        }
    }
}

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Developer
    {
        public static Developer DeveloperIsBorn(string firstName, string lastname)
        {
            return new Developer();
        }

        public Developer MakesAwesomeApp()
        {
            return this;
        }

        public Developer InsertsRecordsIntoDatabaseForLiving()
        {
            return this;
        }

        public void Retires()
        {
           // Not really
        }        
    }
}
```

One more example:

```
using static System.Console;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WriteLine("test");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about the "using static" keyword, thank you for mention it

Answer (score 17):

You could create a static class.

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class MyGlobalClass
    {
        public static void MyMethod() { ... }
    }
}
```

You would then add the namespace in the `using` section of your calling class to access it.  Like this:

```
using MyNamespace;

public class CallingClass
{
    public  void CallingMethod()
    {
        MyGlobalClass.MyMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a static class (even enclose it in it's own namespace so as not to pollute the main project namespace), then call it from anywhere:

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public static class SomeClass
    {
        public static string SomeMethod() 
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your code, you can call it using:

```
string x = SomeNamespace.SomeClass.SomeMethod();
```

Or, you can set up a `using` at the top of the code and just reference it without the namespace:

```
using SomeNamespace;
...
string x = SomeClass.SomeMethod();
```

Comment: I think its seriously misleading to call a namespace GlobalNamespace or to call a class GlobalClass...

Comment: @kol perhaps, but I think saluce was trying to show anonymizer explicitly how the class relates to his question.

Answer (score 0):

@kol is right, there are NO global functions in C#. Take a look at this post [MSDN post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7fbd0c3e-64dd-46f3-b278-2700b7ca8b03/global-functions-in-c-replacement-of-module?forum=csharpgeneral). I would use layers (I renamed your "Module" class to "TransactionsModule") and It would look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace XYZ
{
    public class TransactionsModule
    {
        public List<Person> GetPersons(string query, string connectionString)
        {
            List<Person> dbItems = new List<Person>();

            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

            try 
            {
                conn.Open();
                var cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
                cmd.CommandText = query;

                using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    Person objPerson = new Person();

                    //These are the columns returned
                    objPerson.Name = Convert.ToString(myReader["Name"]);
                    objPerson.Age = Convert.ToInt32(myReader["Age"]);

                    dbItems.Add(objPerson);
                }
            } 
            catch(OleDbException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
            return dbItems;           
        }


    }

    //This class should be in another Layer, but I placed it here since It's a quick Example
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

All the logic was abstracted to the TransactionsModule class, then you only need to call the Method: GetPersons. Take a look:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using XYZ.TransactionsModule;

namespace XYZ
{
    public partial class frmReports : Form
    {      
        public frm1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            protected TransactionsModule moduleTran;
        }

        private void frm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //We initialize the Data Access Layer class
            moduleTran = new TransactionsModule();

            //This ConnectionString should be in your app.config
            string conString = "provider= microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=..\\dbCooperative.mdb";
            string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM table";

            List<Person> ItStaff = moduleTran.GetPersons(sqlQuery, conString);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An addition to the other answers.

Having the static class `Console` form the `System` namespace, then in a new file "Usings.cs" you could add a line

```cs
global using static System.Console;
```

Now its methods like `WriteLine` are available in your whole project - you don't need tot add the using to any other file.