# Is there any function in C# like isnull in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, function

In SQL server we can use "isnull" function for example if Table1 Contains Field1 and only one record which Field1 is null we can write this Query:

```
select isnull(Field1,0) from Table1
```

which returns "0".

can we use any function like this in C#? for Example Consider textBox1 is Empty. and I want to Show "0".

```
MessageBox.show( FunctionName(textBox1.text , 0).toString());
```

Comment: Are you asking about "how to create global function in C#"? (does not exist in the language, see one of many question on the topic - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170383/how-to-declare-global-function-or-method-using-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an extension method:

```
internal static class MyStringExtensions {

   public static string GetValueOrDefault(this string extendee, string defaultValue) {

     if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(extendee)) { return defaultValue;}
     return extendee;
   }
}
```

Sample Use:

```
MessageBox.show( textBox1.text.GetValueOrDefault("0"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) like this:

```
MessageBox.show( textBox1.text ?? "0" );
```

Note that on the right side of the `??` the value needs to be of the same type as on the left side or of a type with an implicit conversion to the left-side type. In the example, both values are of type `string` so everything is fine.

Note also that if the value is empty rather than `null`, the empty string will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it in this way which is as good as using a function:

```
MessageBox.show(String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) ? "" : textBox1.text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
MessageBox.show(String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) ? "0" : textBox1.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own function:

```
int myfun(String text) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [`IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx),

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
```