# C# Function to use as a Global

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have multiple dropdownlist in my page. To load the item, I use the following code:

```
protected void GetItemList()
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ID, Group from TableGroup order by Group"))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();
        cboGroup.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        cboGroup.DataTextField = "Group";
        cboGroup.DataValueField = "ID";
        cboGroup.DataBind();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Then I call the function above when page is load.

My question is, How can I make a single function like my code above where the code is used for multiple dropdownlist?

For instance, All I need to do is just change the query and the dropdownlist Id.

Comment: Look at `SqlParameter`

Comment: @john There are no parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to declare global function or method using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170383/how-to-declare-global-function-or-method-using-c)

Comment: change `GetItemList()` to `GetItemList(string dropDownName)` and pass it to `SqlCommand` via `SqlParameter`

Comment: @Patrick Hofman Based on "All I need to do is just change the query and the dropdownlist Id.", I assumed he needs to filter `TableGroup`' with a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: On the page there's around 10 dropdownlist and the item is from different sources. If I couldn't make a global function, I will create a function like my code 10 times on code behind.

Comment: Is your idea what you want to filter items in `TableGroup`, using an id per list, or do you have multiple database tables which will each populate its own dropdown?

Comment: Each Dropdownlist will get the list from different table, not different database.

Comment: A method which doesn't return anything should not be named `Get...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the DropDownList and Query as Parameters

```
protected void GetItemList(DropDownList ddl, string query, string text, string value)
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            ddl.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            ddl.DataTextField = text;
            ddl.DataValueField = value;
            ddl.DataBind();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Call function like:

```
GetItemList(cboGroup, "select ID, Group from TableGroup order by Group")
```

Comment: I really don't like this. It's an invitation for sql injection. Every method should have a meaningfule name like `FillGroupList`, `FillItemList` or `FillUserList` and the query should be encapsulated there. Also, how can i pass the sql-parameters to this method?

Comment: @TimSchmelter But there is no concatenations here and we hard code the query in the code.

Comment: There will be some day @Sankar

Comment: @TimSchmelter May i ask why you think its a invitation for sql injection if you are the only person who will acess the method from a other method. Basically he is the only one giving input for the GetItemList. No page input is used so.

Comment: @H.Mikhaeljan: because this bad pattern will be used across the whole project. Tomorrow OP will concatenate the sql-query, another day he will let the user enter part of the query. Where can i pass parameters here?

Comment: @TimSchmelter hmm k. Do you have a beter example? i'd love to see a beter way just for my learning. thanx

Comment: @PatrickHofman I understand! But OP scenario doesn't looks like that.

Comment: @H.Mikhaeljan: the better way is to say OP that he should leave it as it is.

Comment: If this answer is not "really" good solution, please show me the best code if you don't mind.

Comment: The DataSource is of type object. It would be better if you decouple the class into two parts. One getting and returning the data from database. The second would be the method GetItemList(object dataSource, string text, string value).

Comment: @PraneetNadkar, Can you give me an example on the answer section please?